# Usage of the "==" operator for three objects

Tags: python, operators, equality

Is there any computational difference between these two methods of checking equality between three objects?

I have two variables: `x` and `y`. Say I do this:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> y = 5
>>> x == y == 5
True
```

Is that different from:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> y = 5
>>> x == y and x == 5
True
```

What about if they are `False`?

```
>>> x = 5
>>> y = 5
>>> x == y == 4
False
```

And:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> y = 5
>>> x == y and x == 4
False
```

Is there any difference in how they are calculated?

In addition, how does `x == y == z` work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Python has chained comparisons, so these two forms are equivalent:

```
x == y == z
x == y and y == z
```

except that in the first, y is only evaluated once.

This means you can also write:

```
0 < x < 10
10 >= z >= 2
```

etc.  You can also write confusing things like:

```
a < b == c is d   # Don't  do this
```

Beginners sometimes get tripped up on this:

```
a < 100 is True   # Definitely don't do this!
```

which will always be false since it is the same as:

```
a < 100 and 100 is True   # Now we see the violence inherent in the system!
```

Comment: bah you should add a note about confusing things probably being bad form .... (example 3)

Comment: Is there a limit on objects to check for equality? ie. Can I use 4 objects: `a == b == c == d`?

Comment: I must say `a < 100 is True` does look surprising, mostly because I would expect `is` to have precedence over other comparisons and thus be treated like `a < (100 is True)`.

Comment: Note that the chain always compares the adjacent elements, so `a == b == c == d` is equivalent to `a == b and b == c and c == d`. It doesn't compare them all to `a`. For numbers (and equality) this rarely matters, but for objects with non-transitive semantics for some of the comparisons it can get strange. For instance, in Python 2, objects of different types compare unequal (unless they are specially coded to be aware of each other), so `decimal.Decimal(0) == fractions.Fraction(0)` is `False`. However, `decimal.Decimal(0) == 0 == fractions.Fraction(0)` is `True`. (Python 3 fixes this.)

Comment: *Help! Help! I'm being repressed!*

Answer (score 0):

Adding a little visual demonstration to already accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13792615/5735010).

For testing equality of three values or variables. We can either use:

```
>>> print(1) == print(2) == print(3)
1
2
3
True

>>> print(1) == print(2) and print(2) == print(3)
1
2
2
3
True
```

The above statements are equivalent but not equal to, since accesses are only performed once. Python chains relational operators naturally. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) docs:

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).

If the functions called (and you are comparing return values) have no side-effects, then the two ways are same.

In both examples, the second comparison will not be evaluated if the first one evaluates to false. However: beware of adding parentheses. For example:

```
>>> 1 == 2 == 0
False
>>> (1 == 2) == 0
True
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13805988/5735010) answer.