# Testing equality of three values

Tags: python

Are these equal?

```
xs[i] == xs[i+1] == xs[i+2]
```

```
xs[i] == xs[i+1] and xs[i+1] == xs[i+2]
```

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792604/usage-of-the-operator-for-three-objects/13792615#13792615

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Python chains such relational operators naturally (including `in` and `is`).

`a() == b() == c()` is *functionally equivalent* to `a() == b() and b() == c()` whenever consecutive calls to `b` return the same value and have the same aggregate side effects as a single call to `b`. For instance, there is no difference between the two expressions whenever `b` is a  pure function with no side-effects.

The easiest way to show the slight difference:

```
>>> print(1) == print(2) == print(3)
1
2
3
True
>>> print(1) == print(2) and print(2) == print(3)
1
2
2
3
True
```

`print()` always returns `None`, so all we are doing is comparing `None`s here, so the result is always `True`, but note that in the second case, `print(2)` is called twice, so we get two `2`s in the output, while in the first case, the result is used for both comparisons, so it is only executed once.

Comment: It's worth noting they are not the same, as it is possible to contrive a scenario where one works and the other fails (`n` is an object that changes the value of `n[i+1]` after an access). Edit: I have edited in an example to show the difference.

Comment: @GarethLatty both of your examples return True. Didn't you mean to put an example where one's False?

Comment: @JoelBerkeley It took me a second to work out what I was trying to show there as well, after 7 years. The point is that they both *return* the same result, but the *side effects* are different: one prints `2` twice. I've added some more explanation to make that clear.

Comment: @GarethLatty it is possible to make it so that one's False and the other True, with a object that updates on every call. I feel that's more at least as important as side efffects. I can add an example

Comment: @JoelBerkeley That is just another example of a side effect, but yeah, no harm in adding more examples to clarify the point.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, however, when the comparisons are chained the *common expression* is evaluated once, when using `and` it's evaluated twice. In both cases the second comparison is not evaluated if the first one is false, example from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent
> to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both
> cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).

Answer (score 17):

As answered by others, the answer is yes.  However: beware of adding parentheses.  For example:

```
>>> 1 == 2 == 0
False
>>> (1 == 2) == 0
True
```

In the second case, `(1 == 2)` evaluates to `False`, and then `False == 0` evaluates to `True`, because Python allows comparison of booleans to integers.

Likewise:

```
>>> 0 == 0 == 1
False
>>> (0 == 0) == 1
True
```

Answer (score 7):

yes you are correct ....

you can also do

```
5 > x > 1
```

or

```
1 < x < 5
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use set collection to test the equality

```
>>> a, b, c = 2, 2, 2
>>> len({a, b, c}) == 1
True
>>> a, b, c = 2, 2, 3
>>> len({a, b, c}) == 1
False
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, at the python's internals the comparison operators returns nor true neither false, they instead return the 'comparison result' object (cannot remember the class name, it was quite in past), and this object provides the **_*lt*_**, **_*gt*_**, **_*eq*_** etc etc methods and become 'responsible' for the final result (and the 'comparison result' is casting to True or False at end of statement). That's a magic of semantic control python provides to you :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can also chain == with !=:

```
>>> a = b = c = 1
>>> a == b == c
True
>>> a == b == c == 1
True
>>> a == b == c == 2
False
>>> a == b == c != 2
True
>>> a == b == c != 1
False
>>>
```