# How to test equality of any 2 of 3 variables in a clean statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm looking for a cleaner way to make the following type of comparison:

```
if x ==  y or y == z or x == z:
    do something
```

While this would be fine in this small example, I'm looking to make comparisons of 24 variables in chunks of 3 (like above) at a time. I'm having a difficult time trying to find a cleaner way to make these statements. Any ideas?

edit: to make this look a little more to what I'm trying to clean up:

```
if(
   #corner 1 
   cube[0] == cube[29] or
   cube[0] == cube[42] or
   cube[29] == cube[42] or
   #corner 2
   cube[2] == cube[9] or
   cube[2] == cube[44] or
   cube[9] == cube[44] or
   #corner 3
   ...
   #corner 8
   ...
   ):
   doSomething
```

Solution thanks to Primusa:

```
corner1 = [cube[0], cube[29], cube[42]]
corner2 = [cube[2], cube[9], cube[44]]
...

if(len(corner1) != len(set(corner1)) or
   len(corner2) != len(set(corner2)) or
   ...)
    dostuff
```

Comment: Put it in a function? Kind of strange to have 24 variables in the first place, though. Could you use a list instead?

Comment: Do you really **need** 24 variables to begin with?

Comment: @Ry All values are in a larger list. For example, I'm trying to compare myArray[0], myArray[3], and myArray[9] to see if any 2 of those 3 values are equal to one another.

Comment: Any logic to which triplets are compared?

Comment: @zwer They are really in a list, and not all individual variables. This was to just simplify the question (at least in my mind).

Comment: @Ry Yes. I'm making a comparison of what would amount to the 3 colors on the corner of a rubiks cube to ensure that no 2 colors are the same. Part of my restrictions has the cube represented as a long, 54 item list.

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth This does look to be a little cleaner (though I'm hoping for something even cleaner than that if possible). Question updated to show a little more accurately what I'm trying to simply.

Comment: @AllenUnderwood [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792604/usage-of-the-operator-for-three-objects/13792615#13792615) this might help you

Comment: What is your definition of 'clean'? You can use `any()` and `itertools.combinations()` to avoid 'manual' comparison but I wouldn't call that clean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to check if any two values in a gigantic list are equal (assuming that your values are hashable):

```
biglist = [LOTS OF STUFF]

if len(biglist) != len(set(biglist)):
    do stuff
```

set() is a python data structure that cannot have duplicates. As a result, if the length of a set != the length of the list, then there must be duplicates in the list, therefore values are equal.

If your values are not hashable, then you can write a helper function to make the code a little nicer:

```
def compare(x, y, z):
    return x==y or y==z or x==z
```

Comment: I do not think this answers the question, they are asking to compare in chunks of three.

Comment: What happens if `x`, `y` or `z` from OP's question are mutable/non-hashable values?

Comment: @ZiyadEdher you can use the solution to compare it in chunks of whatever length you want. OP specified that the values were stored in a list in his comments, so this solution will work fine.

Comment: @Primusa This statement results in True against a small list of [1, 2, 3] when I should see False.

Comment: @AllenUnderwood my apologies i made a typo, it is fixed now :)

Comment: That looks to have done the trick! Thanks for that and for explaining how it works for this particular example!

Comment: @zwer that's a very good point, I added an option for if it wasn't hashable

Comment: @AllenUnderwood I'm glad to help :)

Answer (score -1):

This is pseudocode... How about something like this:

```
class Corner:

    def __init__(self x, y, z):
        self.x = x;
        self.y = y;
        self.z = z;

    def hasMatch(self)
       return x==y || x==z || y==z;
```

Then to use:

```
c = Corner(10,11,10);
hasMatch = c.HasMatch();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a class to do the same. An example is shown below

```
class TripleCompare(object):

    def __init__(self, inpList):
        self.allEle = inpList

    def compare(self):
        resList = []
        for a,b,c in self.allEle:
            resList.append(a==b or b==c or c==a)
        return resList
k=TripleCompare([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]) 
# send your elements like shown above, say TripleCompare([[c[0],c[29],c[49]],[c[21],c[22],c[23]]) (for example)
k.compare()
```

Comment: Since this is aimed at being a test function only, I'm avoiding using a class myself. But you do make a good point!